# Xcode StoryBoard views are disappeared after shutdown

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have placed a few labels and image views inside a prototype cell of a tableview and added constraints.I have saved everything and shutdown my iMac and later I started working again but all the views & constraints in prototype cell are misplaced and I can't see them inside of the cell anymore but I can still see the objects listed I have added in Navigator window. I have faced the same issue earlier as well but then I thought maybe I forgot to save it or did something wrong. The issue raised again and I am using Xcode version 8.0. Please let me know any possible fixes for it or if I am doing wrong anywhere to have this issue.

[image]

Comment: Your constraints are not properly satisfied, once they all are blue then this won't happen.

Comment: @ Inder Kumar Rathore, they were fine before shutdown and that it the image after I reopen the project, thanks.

Comment: You mean to say that all the constraints were blue before shutting down?

Comment: Can you try update frames option from the bottom right icon [Resolve Autolayout Issues]

Comment: Exactly, I have added constraints correctly and they were blue.

Comment: updating frames is not helping either :(.